# Funcion updateOrCreate en laravel comparando con la fecha actual (mes, año)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buen dia compañeros, como puedo usar esta funcion de laravel y que solo realice el update pero cuando el mes y el año coincidan, lo tengo de esta manera

```
$prom = Marcaprom::updateOrCreate(
  [
   'marca_id' => $marca->id,
   'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m'),
  ],
  [
    'promedio' => $total['prom'],
    'marca_id' => $marca->id,
  ]
 );
```

entonces cada que se hace la consulta, me crea un registro en vez de hacer la funcion update, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacer una condición dentro del `updateOrCreate`, el cual consiste en obtener sólo aquellos registros que sean iguales en `año` y `mes` a la fecha actual, de ser así,

```
$currentYear = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
$currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('m');

$prom = Marcaprom::updateOrCreate(
  [
   'marca_id' => $marca->id,
   'created_at' => Marcaprom::whereYear('created_at', '=', $currentYear)->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $currentMonth)->first()->created_at ?? null,
  ],
  [
    'promedio' => $total['prom'],
    'marca_id' => $marca->id,
  ]
 );
```

Incluso en la consulta interna puedes agregar `where('marca_id', $marca->id)` o como tú consideres pertinente.